# Cite caption and figure

Tags: floats, captions, citing

I want to cite a figure and directly cite the caption of the text. That means that I copy the figure and the original caption of the figure.

Is the following solution correct because someone can think that \citep referees only to the caption?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{figure.pdf}
\caption{"This is the caption" \citep[p. 2]{ref-2021}}
\label{fig:covid-dataset}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: When you write that you want to "cite a figure", do you mean to say that you want to cite a publication that has a figure you wish to cross-reference? If not, please clarify what you mean by "cite a figure". Please also clarify why you would appear to think it's necessary to embed the `\citep` directive inside a `\caption` directive inside a `figure` environment.

Comment: So the figure and the caption text are from another paper. I want to show that the figure is copied from the other paper and the caption text is a direct quote. If I copy a figure (but not the caption text), I always add a \citep at the end of the caption with the reference to the source of the figure.

Comment: If the figure is (more or less) a direct reproduction of a figure published elsewhere, I'd say it's not enough to provide a `\cite`-type link. You should also make clear to your readers, *in the caption*, that they're looking at a reproduction. Presumably, it's the entire figure from the publication that matters, not just the caption. Hence, I'd use the `\caption` directive to state unmistakably that the figure is a reproduction of Figure xx from publication yy.

Comment: Some publications provide not only a DOI for the whole article but also a DOI for every single figure, so allowing a specific cite and reference to the figure. But IMHO anyway you must be absolutely clear from what article this image come from,  what text is the original caption and  what is your own text,  as well as clarify in your caption that you have permission to reproduce the figure (author consent, CC license, etc.)  to dispel any doubt about a possible plagiarism.